# How to subscribe to Gazebo pause/play events from a Ros2 python node

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ignition-fortress

I would like my ROS2 python node to react to pause/play events from the Gazebo simulator. I am using ROS2 Iron and Gazebo Fortress (Ignition). My initial thought was to subscribe to the world stats topic from the `WorldControl` plugin. Unfortunately, this does not work because there ros_gz_bridge [does not support the world stats message type](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/blob/iron/ros_gz_bridge/README.md):

```
$ ign topic --info --topic /stats
Publishers [Address, Message Type]:
  tcp://134.214.146.98:39569, ignition.msgs.WorldStatistics
```

Is there a straightforward way to achieve what I am trying to do?